# Selecting from multi-level groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have two dataframes: df with columns `('a', 'b', 'c')` and tf with columns `('a', 'b')`. I do a group-combine on the two common columns in df:

```
grouped_sum = df.groupby(('a', 'b')).sum()
```

How can I "add" the column `c` to `tf` according to `grouped_sum`, i.e.

```
tf[i]['c'] = grouped_sum[tf[i]['a'], tf[i]['b']]
```

for all rows `i` of the second data frame? For a groupby with a single level it works simply by indexing the group with the corresponding column of tf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you groupby with as_index=False you can merge with tf:

```
In [11]: tf = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5]], columns=list('abc'))

In [13]: grouped_sum = df.groupby(['a', 'b'], as_index=False).sum()

In [14]: grouped_sum
Out[14]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  7
1  3  4  5

In [15]: tf.merge(grouped_sum)  # this won't always be the same as grouped_sum!
Out[15]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  7
1  3  4  5
```

*another option is to set a and b as the index of tf*.

Comment: This solves the problem! However, the merged dataframe does not carry over the index from tf. Hence, it does't feel 100% like the operation on a single-indexed group-by. Any further suggestions?